# Start a bash terminal with C using execl / execv and add timeout

Tags: c, linux, bash, terminal, exec

I'd like to create a secondary terminal (which will be the active one later) using fork and then execl (or execv). I managed to do it up to a point but I'm having trouble adding a timeout period.

Currently the code looks like this:
`execl("/bin/timeout", "timeout", "1m", "/bin/bash", NULL);`

I managed to be able to open a terminal using the above command but it won't timeout after 1 minute. This is going to be a child process, the parent process is the session manager.

I'd like the terminal to close connection after the user is being inactive for several minutes (1 minute in the above case). If the user starts giving out commands, the timer should restart. Is my approach ok for this? Why's the terminal not closing after 1 minute?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: `bash` normally ignores the `TERM` signal. Try using the `--signal` option to specify a different signal.

Comment: Does it work if you just run `timeout 1m /bin/bash` from a terminal?

Comment: So which signal should you use? Probably [SIGHUP](https://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_12_01.html) (QUIT is ignored, INT is resent to the foreground process, KILL may be too brutal)

Comment: "*I'd like the terminal to close connection after the user is being inactive for several minutes*" -- `timeout` does not serve this purpose.  It counts only wall time elapsed.  It does not pay attention to user activity.

Comment: Since you're using Bash, and since it will be an interactive shell, you could pre-set the `TMOUT` variable in its environment to the timeout time in seconds.  Bash will then terminate if there is no user input for that amount of time after issuing the prompt.  Users could easily defeat that, however, if that's a concern for you.

Comment: I don't see in your code that you would start a _terminal_ (i.e. something like `xterm`), but a _shell_, and you don't tell us where you run your C program from. Do you have a pty allocated? Is the  bash you are going to start interactive, i.e. can you interact with this bash?

Comment: BTW, I would also try to use the `--foreground` and perhaps `--kill-after=70s` options for the `timeout` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work according to John Bollinger's answer. Set the TMOUT env variable as readonly, it's fine for us even with not being "100% secure". Thanks everyone for answering!